# Allow multi-line strings in XML/Javascript tooltip

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, ecmascript-6, line

I'm creating an SVG with the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg onload="init(evt)"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="application/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="453px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:484px;height:453px;background:#FFFFFF;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 484 453" width="484px" zoomAndPan="magnify">
    <defs>
        <filter height="300%" id="f15vc1a2o1fe31" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1">
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/>
            <feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/>
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <style>
    .tooltip{
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 13px;
      fill:black;
    }
    .tooltip_bg{
      fill: yellow;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
        <![CDATA[
    function init(evt){
      if ( window.svgDocument == null ){
        svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
      }
      tooltip = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip');
      tooltip_bg = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip_bg');
    }
    function ShowTooltip(evt, mouseovertext){
      var el = evt.target;
      var bbox = el.getBBox();
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"x",bbox.x + bbox.width +11);
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"y",bbox.y + bbox.height+27);
      tooltip.firstChild.data = mouseovertext;
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");
      length = tooltip.getComputedTextLength();
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"width",length+8);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"x",bbox.x + bbox.width +8);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"y",bbox.y + bbox.height+11);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visibile");
    }
    function HideTooltip(evt){
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
    }
  ]]>
    </script>
    <g>
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="208.5" y="118.3125"/>
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="408.5" y="292.0703"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="90" x2="90" y1="41.6094" y2="409.125"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="213" x2="213" y1="41.6094" y2="409.125"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="413" x2="413" y1="41.6094" y2="409.125"/>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="106" x="35" y="5"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="92" x="42" y="26.5332">testExportSVG</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="106" x="35" y="408.125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="92" x="42" y="429.6582">testExportSVG</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="155" y="5"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="162" y="26.5332">Web API Step 1</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="155" y="408.125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="162" y="429.6582">Web API Step 1</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="355" y="5"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="362" y="26.5332">Web API Step 2</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="355" y="408.125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="362" y="429.6582">Web API Step 2</text>
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="208.5" y="118.3125"/>
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="408.5" y="292.0703"/>
        <rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="3" style="stroke:#EEEEEE;stroke-width:1.0;" width="477" x="0" y="72.7852"/>
        <line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="477" y1="72.7852" y2="72.7852"/>
        <line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="477" y1="75.7852" y2="75.7852"/>
        <rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24.3516" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.0;" width="207" x="135" y="61.6094"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="193" x="141" y="79.1045">step 1: Account.Account Credit</text>
        <polygon fill="#A80036" points="196.5,114.3125,206.5,118.3125,196.5,122.3125,200.5,118.3125" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="90" x2="202.5" y1="118.3125" y2="118.3125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="97" y="113.4561">1</text>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="79" x="108" y="113.4561">xecmPayload</text>
        <rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="80" x="5" y="131.3125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="72" x="9" y="148.8076">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'input = data;')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
static data 1</a>
        </text>
        <polygon fill="#A80036" points="101,179.0156,91,183.0156,101,187.0156,97,183.0156" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:2.0,2.0;" x1="95" x2="212.5" y1="183.0156" y2="183.0156"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="107" y="178.1592">2</text>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="29" x="118" y="178.1592">[200]</text>
        <rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="101" x="39" y="196.0156"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="93" x="43" y="213.5107">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'otherVar ← other/path;\nsaveV ← /xml/path;\n')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
validation data 1</a>
        </text>
        <rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="3" style="stroke:#EEEEEE;stroke-width:1.0;" width="477" x="0" y="246.543"/>
        <line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="477" y1="246.543" y2="246.543"/>
        <line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="477" y1="249.543" y2="249.543"/>
        <rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24.3516" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.0;" width="296" x="90.5" y="235.3672"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="282" x="96.5" y="252.8623">step 2: Abstraction.loan_bundles_abstraction</text>
        <polygon fill="#A80036" points="396.5,288.0703,406.5,292.0703,396.5,296.0703,400.5,292.0703" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="213.5" x2="402.5" y1="292.0703" y2="292.0703"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="220.5" y="287.2139">3</text>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="165" x="231.5" y="287.2139">create_loan_sanitywatercost</text>
        <rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="80" x="128" y="305.0703"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="72" x="132" y="322.5654">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'some = data')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
static data 2</a>
        </text>
        <polygon fill="#A80036" points="224.5,352.7734,214.5,356.7734,224.5,360.7734,220.5,356.7734" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:2.0,2.0;" x1="218.5" x2="412.5" y1="356.7734" y2="356.7734"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="230.5" y="351.917">4</text>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="29" x="241.5" y="351.917">[204]</text>
        <rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="101" x="163" y="369.7734"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="93" x="167" y="387.2686">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'saveJson ← json.path;\n')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
validation data 2</a>
        </text>
        <!--MD5=[4d7fcf74e484c9aebaed7917263f6fd7]
@startuml 
autonumber 
==step 1: Account.Account Credit== 
"testExportSVG"->"Web API Step 1": xecmPayload 
rnote left "testExportSVG"
static data 1
endrnote 
activate "Web API Step 1"
"testExportSVG" <- - "Web API Step 1": [200] 
rnote over "testExportSVG"
validation data 1
endrnote 
deactivate "Web API Step 1"
==step 2: Abstraction.loan_bundles_abstraction== 
"Web API Step 1"->"Web API Step 2": create_loan_sanitywatercost 
rnote left "Web API Step 1"
static data 2
endrnote 
activate "Web API Step 2"
"Web API Step 1" <- - "Web API Step 2": [204] 
rnote over "Web API Step 1"
validation data 2
endrnote 
deactivate "Web API Step 2"
@enduml

PlantUML version 1.2021.8(Sat Jun 26 01:20:59 PDT 2021)
(GPL source distribution)
Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Default Encoding: UTF-8
Language: en
Country: US
-->
    </g>
    <rect class="tooltip_bg" id="tooltip_bg" x="0" y="0" ry="2" width="55" height="21" visibility="hidden"/>
    <text class="tooltip" id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="hidden">Tooltip</text>
</svg>
```

For one of the tooltips, I want the text to wrap around at the semicolon. I've tried using the word-wrap CSS property to do so, I tried by breaking it up into two strings, I tried with the backslash character, etc. But none of those strategies worked.

```
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="93" x="43" y="213.5107">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'otherVar ← other/path;\nsaveV ← /xml/path;\n')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
validation data 1</a>
</text>
```

So how can I split up those lines, where there are "\n"?

(Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrjvpkdm/4/))

Comment: I have not been following the SVG development closely but I think you would need to throw in `tspan` child elements, one for each "line", stacking them up with the right x/y attributes. Or you would need to use a foreignObject hosting a HTML fragment like a `pre` element instead of the SVG `text`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen but in this case, we're passing the string literal as a function parameter which goes into javascript, how would we adjust accordingly without displacing that

Comment: Well, to create `tspan` elements you would need to split the string and create and add the `tspan` elements. If you go the other route with the `foreignObject` containing an HTML `pre` element you can set the `pre`s `textContent` property to the string without need to break it up. So keeping the function signature is easy, you will probably just need more work in the function body or rather have it call other functions doing the work to e.g. split the string, create the `tspan` elements and their coordinates, insert them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get some prototype working using `tspan` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/9sk5xfz4/1/

```html
<svg onload="init(evt)"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="application/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="453px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:484px;height:453px;background:#FFFFFF;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 484 453" width="484px" zoomAndPan="magnify">
    <defs>
        <filter height="300%" id="f15vc1a2o1fe31" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1">
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/>
            <feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/>
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <style>
    .tooltip{
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 13px;
      fill:black;
    }
    .tooltip_bg{
      fill: yellow;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
        <![CDATA[
    function init(evt){
      if ( window.svgDocument == null ){
        svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
      }
      tooltip = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip');
      tooltip_bg = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip_bg');
    }
    function ShowTooltip(evt, mouseovertext){
      var el = evt.target;
      var bbox = el.getBBox();
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"x",bbox.x + bbox.width +11);
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"y",bbox.y + bbox.height+27);
      const lines = mouseovertext.split('\n');
      if (lines.length === 1)
         tooltip.textContent = mouseovertext;
      else {
         tooltip.textContent = '';
         lines.map((s, p) => { const tspan = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'tspan'); tspan.textContent = s; tspan.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', bbox.x + bbox.width +11); tspan.setAttributeNS(null, 'dy', (p === 0 ? 0 : 15).toString()); return tspan; }).forEach(tspan => tooltip.appendChild(tspan));
      }
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");
      const tooltipBBox = tooltip.getBBox();
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"height",tooltipBBox.height+8);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"width",tooltipBBox.width+8);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"x",bbox.x + bbox.width +8);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"y",bbox.y + bbox.height+11);
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visibile");
    }
    function HideTooltip(evt){
      tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
      tooltip_bg.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
    }
  ]]>
    </script>
    <g>
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="208.5" y="118.3125"/>
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="408.5" y="292.0703"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="90" x2="90" y1="41.6094" y2="409.125"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="213" x2="213" y1="41.6094" y2="409.125"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:5.0,5.0;" x1="413" x2="413" y1="41.6094" y2="409.125"/>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="106" x="35" y="5"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="92" x="42" y="26.5332">testExportSVG</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="106" x="35" y="408.125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="92" x="42" y="429.6582">testExportSVG</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="155" y="5"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="162" y="26.5332">Web API Step 1</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="155" y="408.125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="162" y="429.6582">Web API Step 1</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="355" y="5"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="362" y="26.5332">Web API Step 2</text>
        <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="31.6094" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.5;" width="113" x="355" y="408.125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="99" x="362" y="429.6582">Web API Step 2</text>
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="208.5" y="118.3125"/>
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="64.7031" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="10" x="408.5" y="292.0703"/>
        <rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="3" style="stroke:#EEEEEE;stroke-width:1.0;" width="477" x="0" y="72.7852"/>
        <line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="477" y1="72.7852" y2="72.7852"/>
        <line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="477" y1="75.7852" y2="75.7852"/>
        <rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24.3516" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.0;" width="207" x="135" y="61.6094"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="193" x="141" y="79.1045">step 1: Account.Account Credit</text>
        <polygon fill="#A80036" points="196.5,114.3125,206.5,118.3125,196.5,122.3125,200.5,118.3125" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="90" x2="202.5" y1="118.3125" y2="118.3125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="97" y="113.4561">1</text>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="79" x="108" y="113.4561">xecmPayload</text>
        <rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="80" x="5" y="131.3125"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="72" x="9" y="148.8076">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'input = data;')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
static data 1</a>
        </text>
        <polygon fill="#A80036" points="101,179.0156,91,183.0156,101,187.0156,97,183.0156" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:2.0,2.0;" x1="95" x2="212.5" y1="183.0156" y2="183.0156"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="107" y="178.1592">2</text>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="29" x="118" y="178.1592">[200]</text>
        <rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="101" x="39" y="196.0156"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="93" x="43" y="213.5107">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'otherVar ← other/path;\nsaveV ← /xml/path;')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
validation data 1</a>
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'otherVar ← other/path;\nsaveV ← /xml/path;')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
validation data 1</a>

        </text>
        <rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="3" style="stroke:#EEEEEE;stroke-width:1.0;" width="477" x="0" y="246.543"/>
        <line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="477" y1="246.543" y2="246.543"/>
        <line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="0" x2="477" y1="249.543" y2="249.543"/>
        <rect fill="#EEEEEE" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24.3516" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.0;" width="296" x="90.5" y="235.3672"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="282" x="96.5" y="252.8623">step 2: Abstraction.loan_bundles_abstraction</text>
        <polygon fill="#A80036" points="396.5,288.0703,406.5,292.0703,396.5,296.0703,400.5,292.0703" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" x1="213.5" x2="402.5" y1="292.0703" y2="292.0703"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="220.5" y="287.2139">3</text>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="165" x="231.5" y="287.2139">create_loan_sanitywatercost</text>
        <rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="80" x="128" y="305.0703"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="72" x="132" y="322.5654">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'some = data')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
static data 2</a>
        </text>
        <polygon fill="#A80036" points="224.5,352.7734,214.5,356.7734,224.5,360.7734,220.5,356.7734" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;"/>
        <line style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-dasharray:2.0,2.0;" x1="218.5" x2="412.5" y1="356.7734" y2="356.7734"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" font-weight="bold" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="7" x="230.5" y="351.917">4</text>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="29" x="241.5" y="351.917">[204]</text>
        <rect fill="#FBFB77" filter="url(#f15vc1a2o1fe31)" height="24" style="stroke:#A80036;stroke-width:1.0;" width="101" x="163" y="369.7734"/>
        <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="13" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="93" x="167" y="387.2686">
            <a onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt, 'saveJson ← json.path;\n')" onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)">
validation data 2</a>
        </text>
        <!--MD5=[4d7fcf74e484c9aebaed7917263f6fd7]
@startuml 
autonumber 
==step 1: Account.Account Credit== 
"testExportSVG"->"Web API Step 1": xecmPayload 
rnote left "testExportSVG"
static data 1
endrnote 
activate "Web API Step 1"
"testExportSVG" <- - "Web API Step 1": [200] 
rnote over "testExportSVG"
validation data 1
endrnote 
deactivate "Web API Step 1"
==step 2: Abstraction.loan_bundles_abstraction== 
"Web API Step 1"->"Web API Step 2": create_loan_sanitywatercost 
rnote left "Web API Step 1"
static data 2
endrnote 
activate "Web API Step 2"
"Web API Step 1" <- - "Web API Step 2": [204] 
rnote over "Web API Step 1"
validation data 2
endrnote 
deactivate "Web API Step 2"
@enduml

PlantUML version 1.2021.8(Sat Jun 26 01:20:59 PDT 2021)
(GPL source distribution)
Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Default Encoding: UTF-8
Language: en
Country: US
-->
    </g>
    <rect class="tooltip_bg" id="tooltip_bg" x="0" y="0" ry="2" width="55" height="21" visibility="hidden"/>
    <text class="tooltip" id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="hidden">Tooltip</text>
</svg>
```